# How do you create a type for binary, octet, and hex with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I would simply like to be able to create a type for these data types so I can place restrictions on methods.

```
type hex = 0x;
type octet = 0o;
type binary = 0b;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create literal hex/octal/binary types, but they will all be instances of the `number` type. There is no way to restrict a type to just "hex numbers" or "octals". If you need that feature, I would [file an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues), being sure to explain your use case.

For thoroughness, you *can* declare non-decimal literal types:

```
type A = 255
type B = 0o377
type C = 0xFF
```

Comment: Ah, I see. The use case would have to be with ES6 typed arrays being able to take in any number without any warning signs. They take it in and are converted. But I see I could actually write a type that can restrict the numbers that can be entered.